# Is there a way to change the appeareance of an html text when hovering on the div that contains it?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need to color and zoom the text when the cursor "approaches" the text (so basically when the mouse enters the area of the div surrounding the text). Right now i can make it work coloring the text only when i hover directly on it. I'll paste a snippet of the code.

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" class="max container">
  <div fxFlex="100%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <!--here there is an image-->
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="100%" class="centered-text" fxHide fxShow.gt-lg>
    <h2 [ngClass]="{'gradient' : this.gradient,'lighter':lighter, 'zoom':zoom,  'scale':1.2}" style="margin: 0;" class="font">
      hoverMe
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'iet-box-academy',
  templateUrl: './box-academy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./box-academy.component.scss']
})

export class BoxAcademyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() scale = 1;
  @Input() img = '';
  @Input() title = 'TITOLO';
  @Input() descr = '';
  @Input() align = "centerer";
  @Input() lighter = false;
  @Input() zoom = true;
  @Input() gradient: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.zoom {
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  color: #00D3FF;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wdfc7g9a/14/

Comment: .container:hover .zoom {
transform: scale(1.5);
  color: #00D3FF;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `:hover` to the parent and add a child selector:

Change:

```
.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  color: #00D3FF;
}
```

To:

```
.container:hover .zoom {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  color: #00D3FF;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container:hover .zoom {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is a text
  <div class="zoom">highlight this text</div>
  More text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `centered-text` class instead of `zoom` class. Because it is easier to give a transparent padding to it so you can have the "approaching" animation played without needing to hover directly on the text.
This code will fix your problem the moment you copy paste it to your Custom CSS:

```
.centered-text {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:13px;
}

.centered-text:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  color: #00D3FF;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```